# Complexity of existence of simple polygonalization with prescribed area?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, cg.comp-geom, polygon

This is a followup on my previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328229/what-is-known-about-this-tsp-variant). Fekete proved the NP-completeness of deciding the existence of simple polygonalization with minimum (or maximum) enclosed area (simple polygonalization  is a closed chain of straight line segments that does not cross itself).

I am interested in the complexity of this problem:

Input: Set $S$ of $N$ points on integer 2D grid and a rational number $A$

Question: Is there a polygonalization that has enclosed area $A$?

> Is this problem still NP-complete?

The area $A$ is given as an integer (represented in unary)

Fekete, Sándor P. ["On simple polygonalizations with optimal area."](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FPL00009492#page-1) *Discrete & Computational Geometry* **23**.1 (2000): 73-110

Comment: This was posted on Mathoverflow without getting an answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335417/complexity-of-existence-of-simple-polygonalization-with-prescribed-area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is already contained in Fekete's paper. In Section 3, Fekete shows that the following problem GRID-EMPTY is NP-complete:

> **Problem:** GRID-EMPTY
>   **Instance:** a set $S$ of $n$ grid points in the plane
>   **Question:** Is there a simple polygon on this vertex set $S$ that does not contain any other grid points on its boundary or in its interior?

By Pick's theorem, every simple polygon with grid vertices that has $b$ grid points on its boundary and $i$ grid points in its interior has area $(b+2i-2)/2$.

For the scenario in GRID-EMPTY, the smallest possible area is $(n-2)/2$, and this area can be reached if and only if the answer to the GRID-EMPTY instance is YES.
Hence, you simple have to set $A:=(n-2)/2$ in Fekete's reduction and get NP-completeness of your question.